# How to write only a jts geometry with gml3

Tags: xml, geometry, geotools, jts, gmlib

I have a geometry (JTS) geometry and i want to encode this geometry with GML3

I did this work Gml2 in this way :

```
        GMLWriter writer = new GMLWriter();
        writer.setNamespace(true);
        writer.setSrsName(CRS.toSRS(pa.getFeature().getType().getCoordinateReferenceSystem()));
        final String s = writer.write(pa.getGeometry());
```

and s like below

```
       <gml:MultiPolygon srsName="EPSG:4326">
        <gml:polygonMember>
          <gml:Polygon>
            <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
              <gml:LinearRing>
                <gml:coordinates>388398.01680386113,4234936.561284632 388496.2268063746,4234925.211013514 388486.8865137336,4234818.841002756 388473.5261352561,4234681.43099238 388471.2816094029,4234659.843136447 388370.4591269435,4234691.257276198 388370.45921945036,4234691.2574215075 388386.1865097745,4234829.971280575 388398.01680386113,4234936.561284632</gml:coordinates>
              </gml:LinearRing>
            </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
            <gml:innerBoundaryIs>
              <gml:LinearRing>
                <gml:coordinates>388480.8967599605,4234910.071050081 388470.27675781824,4234910.611079167 388467.16673689516,4234903.311085147 388477.35673742165,4234902.231057049 388480.8967599605,4234910.071050081</gml:coordinates>
              </gml:LinearRing>
            </gml:innerBoundaryIs>
          </gml:Polygon>
        </gml:polygonMember>
        <gml:polygonMember>
          <gml:Polygon>
            <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
              <gml:LinearRing>
                <gml:coordinates>388471.2816094029,4234659.843136447 388471.2820757456,4234659.842991144 388471.28158315114,4234659.842883958 388471.2816094029,4234659.843136447</gml:coordinates>
              </gml:LinearRing>
            </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
          </gml:Polygon>
        </gml:polygonMember>
      </gml:MultiPolygon>
```

is there any way to do this in GML3?

i need gml:posList tag not gml:coordinates

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GeoTools then you could follow the [XML Geometry Tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/xml/geometry.html). So something like:

```
SimpleFeatureType TYPE = DataUtilities.createType("location", "geom:Point,name:String");

File locationFile = new File("location.xsd");
locationFile = locationFile.getCanonicalFile();
locationFile.createNewFile();

URL locationURL = locationFile.toURI().toURL();
URL baseURL = locationFile.getParentFile().toURI().toURL();

FileOutputStream xsd = new FileOutputStream(locationFile);

GML encode = new GML(Version.GML3);
encode.setBaseURL(baseURL);
encode.setNamespace("location", locationURL.toExternalForm());
encode.encode(xsd, TYPE);

xsd.close();

WKTReader2 wkt = new WKTReader2();
List<SimpleFeature> collection = new LinkedList<SimpleFeature>();
collection.add(SimpleFeatureBuilder.build(TYPE, new Object[] { wkt.read("POINT (1 2)"),"name1" }, null));
collection.add(SimpleFeatureBuilder.build(TYPE, new Object[] { wkt.read("POINT (4 4)"),"name2" }, null));

ByteArrayOutputStream xml = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

GML encode2 = new GML(Version.GML3);
encode2.setLegacy(true);
encode2.setBaseURL(baseURL);
encode2.setNamespace("location", "location.xsd");
encode2.encode(xml,  new ListFeatureCollection(TYPE, collection));

xml.close();

String gml = xml.toString();
```

Comment: hi iant , i try this way but i have a only geometry and crs this is made all of the featurecollection ı want to get only geometry tag

Comment: create a feature that only contains the geometry? it's not really GML if you leave everything else off.

Comment: thanks iant, we found the problem there is no method for GML3 in GML class only version 2 is working. When you give version.gml3 whatever yo did is not important because encode2(in my code) not have a option for gml3 we open source and checked it

Comment: You'll need to use the GeoTools GML class not the JTS one.